# regex to extract string from pattern

Tags: regex

I need to extract a string from the following format:

```
column titlelaufend33max
```

I am interested in `laufend`

so the regex should remove `column title` and then take everythink until the first digit

Answer (score 0):

The regex below will match any string that contains `column title` and has a digit after the portion you are interest in:

```
"column\stitle([A-Za-z]+)\d"
```

The regular expression also contains a capture group, which will capture the portion you are interested into, assuming it's only made up of letters.

Depending on language used, small variations might be needed, but that should be it.

Also saved on regex101 at https://regex101.com/r/gO9kod/1

Answer (score 0):

This should work: `((column title)(.*[^\d])([0-9]))` then just extract group 3

Answer (score 0):

If your regex engine supports `look behind`, then this will do:

```
(?<=column\stitle)[^\d]+
```

It looks behind for the literal string: '`column title`', then matches one or more of any char `not being a digit`.

That should give you what you want.